# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: PosixPath('...')

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver, file-permissions, python-venv, pathlib

1. For context, I'm running this on *MacOS Big Sur 11.0.1* and the relevant variables in play here are:

- Python 3.8
- Selenium
- Chromedriver
- pathlib
- venv
- pip3

2. I'm writing a web automation script that uses *Selenium* and *Chromedriver*.  I used *venv* and *pip3* to install both locally in the project folder; the virtual environment is currently active (using `source bin/activate`).      Within the program I use *pathlib* to get the path of *chromedriver* `current_path = pathlib.Path.cwd()`, which I hand to *Selenium's webdriver* upon instantiation.  `chromedriver_path = current_path / 'lib/python3.8/site-packages/chromedriver'`
3. The program immediately raised this error and traceback message:

```
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 72, in start
    self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1702, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: PosixPath('/Users/nick/Developer/Ubiquiti-AP-Automation/lib/python3.8/site-packages/chromedriver')
```

4. This then causes a secondary error and traceback message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 130, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 31, in main
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = chromedriver_path)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 86, in start
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable may have wrong permissions. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

5. I ran `chmod -R 777 .` in the root of this project file `Ubiquiti-AP-Automation`, and I've double checked that every single file in the subfolders is full read, write, execute permissions for Owner, Group, and Other just in case.  Here is the output when I run `ls -l` in the root folder:

```
total 24
drwxrwxrwx  13 nick  staff   416 Nov 17 18:18 bin
drwxrwxrwx   2 nick  staff    64 Nov 16 14:48 include
drwxrwxrwx   4 nick  staff   128 Nov 18 13:56 lib
-rwxrwxrwx@  1 nick  staff  5515 Nov 18 15:18 main.py
-rwxrwxrwx   1 nick  staff   114 Nov 16 14:48 pyvenv.cfg
```

6. My best guess is that *pathlib* doesn't have the correct permissions even though it does???  Does a python script have different permissions than the person running the script?  I've tried most if not all of the top answers on StackOverflow for this problem over the past 3 days now.  Clearly I'm missing something, but I'm not sure what - any insight would be much appreciated!  Thank you!

Comment: what is `/Users/nick/Developer/Ubiquiti-AP-Automation/lib/python3.8/site-packages/chromedriver` ? a file? a directory?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre it's a directory that has `__init__.py` and `__pycache__` in it.  `__pycache__` is also a directory which has the file `__init__.cpython-38.pyc` within that.

Comment: it looks like you're trying to execute the directory. I think the API is expecting a real executable

Comment: Hmm yea that's silly of me.  I didn't see an executable in there but thought it was ok from the error message.  It seems that `pip3` installs all but non MacOS versions of chromedriver in the `site-packages` folder, so it's the correct location but wrong software.  `brew install chromedriver` downloads the correct software, but puts it in `usr/local` which ruins the point of using `venv` doesn't it?

Comment: well, the package depends on some external non-python package, so I wouldn't be so harsh :)